# are there loops in t-sql ? is using them a good idea?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Pardon me if I'm asking this, but I'm not a SQL Server nor SQL developer.

i have a CSV that i import into a table let's call it T that i create on the fly in SQL Server 2005.

what i would like to do is to run some queries against other tables based on the data imported into the table T i created.
example :

```
select * 
from TableX 
where customerID = [this should contain the customerID from the table T]
```

and then if i find it, i need to update the same table T, if not i move along... until the last record in that csv file. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx

Comment: Have you considered using a join?

Comment: I don't know how, and i rarely use SQL...will consider learning it one day...:)

Comment: Yes, they exist. And using them tends to be a very bad idea - SQL Server is optimized for set based operations not looping. When you use loops in SQL Server, chances are good that you are killing performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No loop necesary for what you want, it seems that you only need `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableX
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM TableT)
```

If you need to update `TableX` with some mark if exists on `TableT`, it should be:

```
UPDATE TableX
SET Mark = 1
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM TableT)
```

If you need to update `TableX` with some value from `TableT`, it should be something like this:

```
UPDATE X
SET X.Column = T.Column
FROM TableX X
INNER JOIN TableT T
ON X.CustomerID = T.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 3):

Looping is a red flag in SQL and is not usually needed. SQL is based on [set theory](http://seanmehan.globat.com/blog/2011/12/20/set-theory-and-sql-concepts/). Understand JOINs and you will rarely need to iterate.

So, in your case, no, looping is neither necessary nor a good idea.

Comment: thanks, how can i join the two tables and update at the same time ?

Comment: @user1327073 `SELECT * 
    FROM TableX AS tX
    JOIN T ON T.customerID = tX.customerID` This will return results ONLY where customerID is the same in both tables. (obviously, change `T.customerID` to the column name you're trying to search against)

Comment: what about customers from both ? like a union not an intersection ?